# WCF (.NET Core) - как указать адрес расположения сервиса, чтобы потом подключиться к нему?

Tags: .net, wcf, address

Мне требуется создать сервис на WCF и подключиться к нему (клиент серверное приложение). Как задать адрес, по которому он будет расположен? Включая адрес в сети, номер порта и имя сервиса.
На [сайте MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0#environmentname) (раздел URL-адреса) показано как подключить прослушиваемые порты для того, чтобы потом это использовать в ссылке при подключении клиента. Однако это для веб-приложений (IWebHostBuilder). Как это сделать не для веб-приложений, а для HostBuilder?
Или я неправильно понимаю концепцию и это единственный способ?